# cannot drop NOT NULL constraint on a DEFAULT ON NULL column

Tags: plsql, null, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I have a table `A` with schema.

```
Name     Null?    Type         
-------- -------- ------------ 
NAME              VARCHAR2(10) 
TABLE_ID NOT NULL NUMBER
```

I wanted `Table_ID` to be an `auto-incrementing` column so I created a sequence.

```
create sequence table_id minvalue 1 start with 1 cache 10;
```

and I modified the `Table_ID` column as

```
alter table A
modify table_id default on null table_id.nextval;
```

***now I cannot drop the table or the column or the constraint.***

It is giving me this **error**.

```
An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

ORA-30667: cannot drop NOT NULL constraint on a DEFAULT ON NULL column
30667.0000 -  "cannot drop NOT NULL constraint on a DEFAULT ON NULL column"
*Cause:    The NOT NULL constraint on a DEFAULT ON NULL column could not be
           dropped.
*Action:   Do not drop the NOT NULL constraint on a DEFAULT ON NULL column.
           The only way to drop the constraint is to remove the ON NULL
           property of the column default.
Vendor code 30667
```

***I have tried to purge the recyclebin but it is not working either***.

I read other posts but none of this seems to make sense.

Please help.

Comment: What statement did you execute that caused the error ? You say "now I cannot drop the table or the column or the constraint" - what does that mean ? It would make sense to provide a complete reproducible example.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to remove the constraint, just set a default value on that column. The constraint will be removed automatically:

```
alter table a modify table_id default 0;
```

Full example:

```
create table a(name varchar2(10), table_id number not null);
create sequence table_id minvalue 1 start with 1 cache 10;
alter table a modify table_id default on null table_id.nextval;
select * from user_constraints where table_name = 'A'; -- one constraint "TABLE_ID" IS NOT NULL
alter table a drop constraint SYS_C0026367; -- ORA-30667: cannot drop NOT NULL constraint on a DEFAULT ON NULL column
alter table a modify table_id default 0;
alter table a drop constraint SYS_C0026367; -- ORA-02443: Cannot drop constraint  - nonexistent constraint
select * from user_constraints where table_name = 'A'; -- the constraint was dropped automatically
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran this code on Oracle Database 19c Standard Edition 2 Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production and it worked fine:

```
create table a(name varchar2(10), table_id number not null);
create sequence table_id minvalue 1 start with 1 cache 10;
alter table a modify table_id default on null table_id.nextval;
drop table a;

Table A created.
Sequence TABLE_ID created.
Table A altered.
Table A dropped.
```

Comment: OP is trying to drop the not null constraint, not the table itself. That is what the error message indicates.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I don't have enough points to upvote your answer that's why I am commenting here.